# ModelState no valida si un input es disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tengo una pequeña consulta, tengo la opción de registro en un formulario realizado en ASP.CORE MVC pero al momento de realizar la siguiente validación `if (ModelState.IsValid)` me arroja `Invalid` un input que tengo como `disabled` a que se debe el error? o tengo algo que corregir en mi codigo de guardado?

```
  private async Task<bool> Guardar_Tratamiento_Async()
    {
        _dataInput = MODEL_TRATAMIENTO;
        var valor = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid) -- invalid el input estado
        {
            var TratLista = _context.TBL_TRATAMIENTO.Where(u => u.TRA_CONCEPTO.Equals(MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.TRA_CONCEPTO)).ToList();
            if (TratLista.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
                await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                {
                    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var Nuevo_Tratamiento = new MODELO_TRATAMIENTO
                            {
                                TRA_CONCEPTO = _dataInput.TRA_CONCEPTO.ToUpper(),
                                TRA_VALOR = _dataInput.TRA_VALOR,
                                TRA_POR_DESC = _dataInput.TRA_POR_DESC,
                                TRA_DESC = _dataInput.TRA_DESC,
                                TRA_TOTAL = _dataInput.TRA_TOTAL,
                                TRA_ESTADO = _dataInput.TRA_ESTADO -- aquí cae en excepción debido al estado disabled del input

                            };
                            await _context.AddAsync(Nuevo_Tratamiento);
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                            transaction.Commit();
                            _dataInput = null;
                            valor = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _dataInput.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            valor = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                _dataInput.ErrorMessage = $"El Tratamiento {MODEL_TRATAMIENTO.TRA_CONCEPTO} ya se encuentra Registrado";
                valor = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    _dataInput.ErrorMessage += error.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            valor = false;
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por diseño de html, un elemento deshabilitado no es enviado en el request al servidor.

Lo que te recomiendo es habilitar el campo con javascript en la acción del submit de la forma

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input id="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Y el javascript

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getelementbyid('name').disabled='';
}
```

Comment: De preferencia siempre tendré que laborar con el input en estado readonly?

Comment: Depende mucho del requerimiento, pero en genera un elemento que continuamente está en readonly muy probablemente no debería de estar.